# python 3 how to pass a dictionary from a list

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I have been having trouble passing a dictionary from a list into another function. I am pretty sure it is because my dictionary is in a list of dictionaries.

Example:

what i want is: `{"part": x2f5, "color": red, "amount": 10}`

What I am getting when I am passing to the function: `[{part": x2f5, "color": red, "amount": 10}]`

```
if (len(order["inventory"]) >= 1):
    #I want to double check here if the part is already in the order 
    if new_order["part"] in (i["part"] for i in order["inventory"]):
        if already_in(new_order, order["inventory"]):
```

Let me know if I should add more information.

Comment: Please can you add what `order["inventory"]` is, the code for function `already_in`, and the full traceback if you're seeing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def the_function(*s):
   pass

m = [{"part": x2f5, "color": red, "amount": 10}]
the_function(*m)
```

This solution will allow you to pass "n" number of dictionary items from a list to `the_function`.

Comment: What if i dont know what the values will be?

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot everyone!

I was however able to solve it myself here it is how i did it if anyone is curious

```
for i in order["inventory"]:
   if (i["part"] == new_order["part"]):
      if (already_in(new_order, i)):
```